# SQL -- How do I write a select statement that finds customers who placed orders on 5 consecutive days

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, gaps-and-islands

orderId, orderDate, customerId are the relevant fields here.

A customer may have more than 1 5-day streak.

What I want the output to look like is something like this

> ```
> customerID  startDate       endDate      numDays 
> 1           2020/01/01      2020/01/05    5
> 1           2020/10/1       2020/10/10   10
> 101         2020/04/10      2020/04/15    6
> ```

So far, this is what I have:

```
    ;
with t1 as (

    select distinct o.idcustomer,orderdate, dateadd(dd,1,orderdate) nextOrderDate, 1 as tday, orderstatus
    from orders o
        join customers c on c.idcustomer=o.idcustomer
    where orderstatus in (3,4) and c.customertype=0
), t2 as (
    select * from t1
    union all
    select o2.idcustomer, o2.orderdate, dateadd(dd,1,o2.orderdate), o.tday+1, o2.orderstatus
    from t1 o2
        join t2 o on o2.idcustomer=o.idcustomer and o2.orderdate=o.nextOrderDate and o2.orderstatus in (3,4)
)

--select idcustomer, max(tday) DaysInARow, min(orderDate) StartDate, max(orderdate)  endDate
select idcustomer, dateadd(dd,-5,min(orderdate)) firstOrderDate, max(orderdate) lastOrderDate
from t2 
where tday>=5
group by idcustomer, tday
order by idcustomer
```

Comment: Hi - please tag your question with the database you are using. Thanks

Comment: Can a customer order twice on the same day?

Comment: They can but I thought the first CTE took care of that. It creates a table with a distinct customerID and orderDate.

Comment: @Chris Have a look @ the answer I provided.

Comment: @OptimalPrime, I did. It generated too many errors and false records. TRUNC is not recognized; The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.


And even when I accounted for those, it did not return the correct data:

40458 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 2017-10-24 00:00:00.000 1901-03-26 00:00:00.000

for instance.

Comment: @OptimalPrime -- oh....this looks like Oracle. Been a while but I think you nailed it had this been an oracle db. I'm using MSSQL/sql-server

Comment: @Chris thanks! .. I thinkit's not that hard for me to convert it into ms sql.. not sure though if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone!

This is the code that gives me what I need:

```
    ;
with t1 as (

    select distinct o.idcustomer,orderdate
    from orders o
        join customers c on c.idcustomer=o.idcustomer
    where orderstatus in (3,4) and c.customertype=0
)
select idCustomer, min(orderdate) startdate, max(orderdate) enddate, count(*) cnt
from (
    select idcustomer, orderdate, 
        row_number() over(partition by idcustomer order by orderdate) rn
    from t1
) t
group by idcustomer, dateadd(day, -rn, orderdate)
having count(*) >= 5 
order by idcustomer, cnt
```

The CTE gives me a unique idCustomer and orderdate (eliminates multiple orders on the same day) and from there, I used @GMB's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb) first example to create the output.

Very cool answer using the row_number to calculate the date grouping.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, where you want to group together consecutive days where a customer had an order.

If a customer has at most one order per day, you can build groups using date arithmetics against an incrementing sequence. Assuming that you are running SQL Server, as the syntax of your current query suggests:

```
select customer_id, min(orderdate) startdate, max(orderdate) enddate, count(*) cnt
from (
    select c.customerid, o.orderdate, 
        row_number() over(partition by customerid order by o.orderdate) rn
    from orders o
    inner join customers c on c.idcustomer = o.idcustomer
    where o.orderstatus in (3, 4) and c.customertype = 0
) t
group by c.customer_id, dateadd(day, -rn, o.orderdate)
```

If you want to display only streaks of 5 days of more, just add a `having` clause:

```
having count(*) >= 5
```

And, if you just want the greatest streak per customer (with a minimum length of 5):

```
select *
from (
    select customer_id, min(orderdate) startdate, max(orderdate) enddate, count(*) cnt,
        rank() over(partition by customer_id order by count(*) desc) rn2
    from (
        select c.customerid, o.orderdate, 
            row_number() over(partition by customerid order by o.orderdate) rn
        from orders o
        inner join customers c on c.idcustomer = o.idcustomer
        where o.orderstatus in (3, 4) and c.customertype = 0
    ) t
    group by c.customer_id, dateadd(day, -rn, o.orderdate)
    having count(*) >= 5
) t
where rn2 = 1
```

If there are duplicates `(customerid, orderdate)`, then we use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`, and `count(distinct orderdate)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: Nice answer, but why would anyone ever assume that a customer will only ever place one order per day?

Comment: @jleach: we can easily handle duplicates with a few tweaks to the query (the overall logic remains the same). I updated my answer to mention that.

Comment: thanks, sorry to sound nitpicky but I thought it might be worth mention in what's maybe a 1 in 1000 case in practice.

Comment: I thought my first cte took care of that. It is distinct customerid and orderdate. It creates a table that has only 1 order per date

Comment: This returns such results like this:

98816 2018-04-18 00:00:00.000 2020-10-12 00:00:00.000 7
34795 2019-03-15 00:00:00.000 2019-11-04 00:00:00.000 5
98816 2018-04-13 00:00:00.000 2020-10-22 00:00:00.000 7
98816 2018-07-05 00:00:00.000 2020-06-01 00:00:00.000 5
34795 2018-02-26 00:00:00.000 2020-02-27 00:00:00.000 15
98816 2020-04-06 00:00:00.000 2020-05-31 00:00:00.000 11

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach and begin with a query like the following:

[SQLFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=71f42cebc2ab957b52c8b24514b1e9c7)

```
WITH truncatedQueries as (
select distinct idcustomer, TRUNC(orderDate) as orderDate from orders 
),
rawData as (
select a.idcustomer,a.orderDate as order1, b.orderDate as order2, b.orderDate-a.orderDate  from truncatedQueries a inner join 
truncatedQueries b on 
a.idcustomer = b.idcustomer AND a.orderDate < b.orderDate  AND
 b.orderDate-a.orderDate =1
),
intervals as (
select idCustomer as CustomerId, min(order1) as StartDate, max(order2) as EndDate from rawData
group by idCustomer order by idCustomer
)
select CustomerId,StartDate, EndDate, endDate - StartDate as numDays  from intervals where endDate - StartDate >=5;
```

The algorithm is the following:

1. I truncate the times from the dates, and do a `distinct` query. By doing this I get 1 entry per order per customer per date.
2. I then do a self-join, of these results to each other and look for consecutive days. I fnd consecutive days by keeping only the rows that have a 1 day difference between 2 orders (of the same customer).
3. Then I end up with results like the following:

> ```
> ID    ORDERDATE   ORDERDATE   DIFFERENCE
>     1 22-APR-11   23-APR-11   1
>     1 23-APR-11   24-APR-11   1
>     2 22-APR-11   23-APR-11   1
> ```

Then we have the basic data, but we are missing two more things:

A) The start of the interval
B) The end of  the interval
C) The difference between them (number of days)

4. For this, I used the `min` and `max` functions. If we get the `min` from the first orderDate column, and the `max` from the second `orderDate` column we have the results. The last part is to do the subtraction and to check for `>=5` if necessary.